# Open multiple mini window with same URL, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am not able to open multiple windows with the same url in a page, each time when window.open is getting called in a for loop, the old mini window's content is getting replaced by new content. But I wanted not to replace the content but open a new window separately.

JavaScript code:

```
function OpenMultipleWindows() {
    var winContent = ['Page1', 'Page2', 'Page3', 'Page4']
    for (var i = 0; i < winContent.length; i++) {
        (function (text) {
            var newWin = open('/localFolder/window.html', 'Print', 'width=500,height=500', '_blank');
            newWin.document.body.innerHTML = winContent[text];
        }(i));
    }
}

$(function () {
    OpenMultipleWindows();
});
```

And `window.html` html code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/VBScript">
        document.write "<object ID='WB' WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
        Sub printitinvb()
         On Error Resume Next
         OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
         OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
         OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
         call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 1)
         End Sub
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printit() {
            printitinvb();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload='printit();'>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is, that you don't change the identifier of your popup.
You may try something like this:

```
function OpenMultipleWindows() {
    var winContent = ['Page1', 'Page2', 'Page3', 'Page4'];
    for (var i = 0; i < winContent.length; i++) {
        (function (text) {
            var newWin = open('/localFolder/window.html', 'Print' + i, 'width=500,height=500', '_blank');
            newWin.document.body.innerHTML = winContent[text];
        }(i));
    }
}

$(function () {
    OpenMultipleWindows();
});
```

The second parameter is the identifier and must be unique.

//EDIT: Add note as an answer of the comment

You need to wait until the document was loaded within the popup. I normally add a JavaScript Element for that. But you can do it like that I think (untested):

```
function addTextToPopup(handle, text){
    if (!handle|| handle.closed) return;
    var bodyElem = handle.document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    if (!bodyElem || bodyElem.length !== 1){
        //check again after a short period
        window.setTimeout(function(){
             addTextToPopup(handle, text);
        }, 250);
        return;
    }

    handle.document.body.innerHTML = winContent[text];
}

function OpenMultipleWindows() {
    var winContent = ['Page1', 'Page2', 'Page3', 'Page4'];
    for (var i = 0; i < winContent.length; i++) {
        (function (text) {
            var newWin = open('/localFolder/window.html', 'Print' + i, 'width=500,height=500', '_blank');
            addTextToPopup(newWin, winContent[text]); 
        }(i));
    }
}

$(function () {
    OpenMultipleWindows();
});
```

If that doesn't work try to append a JS-variable like `domIsReady = false;` and set it to true on popup html onload event and check if this is true with `newWin.domIsReady === true`

Comment: @DaKirsche: Now window problem resolved, but text is not staying for long, text is there in window when it opening but it seems lost after window loaded... any idea?

Comment: I tried something similar where I tried opening different urls in different tabs, but the contents where getting mixed up. I resolved it by giving a time-buffer in between opening tabs in loop. 500ms was enough to prevent the mix-up from happening.